# Migrating from Zendesk to Service Cloud - Rich Text Private/Internal Notes?

Tags: service-cloud-console, servicecloud, macros, inputrichtext, comments

We are long time Zendesk Users and are working to migrate to Service Cloud.
In Zendesk there are basically 2 types of Ticket Notes/Comments

1. Public Reply - shared with Customer
2. Internal Note - shared with Agents

Both of these notes support Rich Text formatting including inline images, lists, code snippets, etc. These also support Macros and the Zendesk native Quick Text.

We can mimic the functionality of the the Public Replies using the Email posts in Service Cloud.

However I am struggling to find a suitable replacement for the Internal Notes.  Our Tickets are quite complex so the Team adds a lot of detail to the Internal Notes. They rely heavily on the Rich Text formatting and macros.

The Body field on the Case Comment does not support Rich Text so we have ruled out using this.
Chatter Posts do support Rich Text however it does not appear that they Support Macros or Quick Text.

What would be the best way to support internal/Private Case Comments with the following requirements

- Rich Text Formatting - inline images, code snippets, etc.
- Macro & Quick Text Support